# html jquery - print specific image in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I have an html page with a link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print QR code</a>
```

When a user clicks it, it does what you think it will.. prints the whole page.. sadly, it does not print the QR code at all. How do I specify what I want to print? Like, lets say I want to print a specific image on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this plugin that does the trick:

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

```
$('img#some_id').printElement();
```

Comment: Ah cool saweet man will remove my post check this out: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm **or** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674425/can-i-modify-this-javascript-to-print-images-from-div if need be

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but just wanted to share you this solution that worked very well without using jquery.

http://www.codescratcher.com/javascript/print-image-using-javascript/#comment-762

Comment: Please include some content fromthe link.