# Print the image by URL from browser's scripts

Tags: javascript, html, printing, vbscript, web-scripting

I can use any browser on windows XP or 7. I can change any security options for my issue to be solved.

I need to print the contents of remote image (by its uri) from javascript or vbscript.
I have a printer installed and I have its name.

**Tha main thing of this question** is to print without any dialog confirmations. I am fully understand the security side of the question, however, exactly because of this I can make any changes to browser's options.

I have tried this (found on the internet):

```
// in-browser vbscript
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
shell.Run ("mspaint /pt ""C:\temp\ticket.png"" ""CUSTOM TG2480-H""")
```

But this does not seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure that you have use the double quotation signs? Have you tried to escape the inner quotation signs with a backslash?

Comment: @reporter I am sure this script runs in general Windows environment, but not in browser's web page.

Comment: Only in an InternetExplorer enviroment does this script run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Answer 1 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175893/html-jquery-print-specific-image-in-page). Similar problem at another thread (html jquery - print specific image in page).

Comment: Sorry, this will open the dialog window which is I dont want.