# printing multiple images on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a print button which prints images individually, I used media print() and windows.print()

```
    <style type="text/css">
@media print {
* { display:none; }
.printMe { display:block }
}
</style>
```

javascript

```
    $('.printMe').click(function() {  
   window.print();  
    return false;  
  });
```

html

```
   <li id="outprint"><a href="#">
   <img src="jqe13/image/print.PNG" class="printMe" alt="Print" title="Print"></a></li>
```

here the images in this li are dynamically generated..for individual images I've done this..
which functions do I use if I need to print all the images by clicking a printAll button 
can anyone help?

Comment: Your almost there buddy ,just use the same class `.printMe` for all the images which you want to be printed or displayed on screen  and thats it :) you existing functionality will work smoothly

Comment: I seriously dont get it who could upvote this question ?

Comment: i used but its nt wrking

Comment: :can u simulate the same on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: is this what u wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/zTYzu/

Comment: No. i want to trigger the printer on clicking a button to print multiple images..http://jsfiddle.net/e6t2n/ check this. i need to print all the images with another print button

Comment: @dreamweiver you there?

Comment: I guess this SO would solve your problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674425/can-i-modify-this-javascript-to-print-images-from-div. only thing you need to keep in mind is that, you gotta give the id of the div which contains all your images.

Comment: that helped ..mine were dynamicall generated images.i'm not getting the single image in the pop up window

Comment: ok, if its dynamically generated images, which are scattered across different elements, then you can write a function to extract all images and place them in a single div for temporary basis and call the print function as mentioned in previously given SO .

Comment: they are in one div..actually i tried the same to print individual images, the pop up dint show any image it showing 'null'.I passed the div id in which the images are there

Comment: Can u update this behavior in your fiddle, i`ll check it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e6t2n/4/ I used this in the frst..but it dint work.i ain't knowing whether its correct or not.now i used the SO u posted..it dint work too

Comment: @dreamweiver hey its working for single image..mine are dynamically generated ..and its working only for the last image even if i click any of the images

Comment: Let me see what i can do, i`m held up wit lot of things as of now.

Comment: okay.If u have any time help me with this .